# Induction equation - derivation

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Where this minus disappear, please?

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec J$ is the current density.

$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec B)= \nabla (\nabla \cdot \vec B)-\nabla ^2 \vec B$  with the first term of the right hand side being zero.

Comment: Thank you very much